# How to get information from API

Tags: json, api

pardon this question as I am very new to this whole API thing. Did a bunch of googling and watched videos etc. but I'm still having troubles getting it to work.

I would like to be able to query this table here: https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/dataset/xubh-q36u , for eg finding the list of hospital & info in San Francisco in json format.

I've tried
https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/metastore/schemas/dataset/items/xubh-q36u?city=san%20francisco

and
https://data.cms.gov/resource/xubh-q36u.json

but they don't work.

Would greatly appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql/?query=[SELECT%20*%20FROM%209d7d6c61-7fbb-5281-950a-6f911567b15d][WHERE%20city%20=%20%22%25san%20Francisco%25%22];](https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql/?query=%5BSELECT%20*%20FROM%209d7d6c61-7fbb-5281-950a-6f911567b15d%5D%5BWHERE%20city%20=%20%22%25san%20Francisco%25%22%5D;)

just send get request to this url to get list of hospitals in San Francisco .
also you can write any SQL query you want to retrieve data from this api

Comment: hi @Amin appreciate your help. is there a way to get it without SQL? like what is taught in this page: https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/202949298-Where-do-I-find-the-API-Endpoint-

i tried but it didnt work for this.